# Django: Template posting random letters instead of correct variable

Tags: python, django

In a template, I have the following:

```
{% for t,k in draft_l %}
    <li>
        <div id="name_area"><span>{{ t }}</span></div>
        <ul id="tool_area">
            <li>Edit</li>
            <li>Publish</li>
            <li>Rename</li>
            <li>Delete</li>
            <li style="display: none;">{{ k }}</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

This is the view:

```
user = request.user
user_drafts = Draft.objects.filter(user = user)
drafts = dict()
for d in user_drafts:
    drafts[d.title] = d.id
alertnum = get_alertnum(user)
return render_to_response('Posting/Pages/posting_draft.html', {'STATIC_URL':STATIC_URL, 'draft_l' : drafts, 'selected':"dr", 'alertnum': alertnum})
```

The value of k seems to be random letters. When I added a print statement to the for loop, all of the numbers for the ID seemed right. Could you comment if you think it "should work"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{% for t,k in draft_l.items %}
```

Templates work a little differently than native python. Notice the `.items`.

Comment: I got this error `Could not parse the remainder: '()' from 'draft_l.items()'
`

Comment: My bad, it's just `.items`. No parentheses.